# jQuery templates with groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using trying to create a template using the jQuery template plugin that has a group header. **The group headers are not known before hand** as it is data driven. The template I have is:

```
<div class='category'>${Category}</div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='${Id}'>${Name}</a></div>
```

The data I have is:

```
var movies = [
    { Name: "Meet Joe Black", Category: "First", Id: 1 },
    { Name: "The Mighty", Category: "First", Id: 2 },
    { Name: "City Hunter", Category: "First", Id: 3 },
    { Name: "A movie", Category: "Second", Id: 4 },
    { Name: "Blade Runner", Category: "Third", Id: 5 }
];
```

I want the output to be

```
<div class='category'>First</div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='1'>Meet Joe Black</a></div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='2'>The Mighty</a></div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='3' >City Hunter</a></div>

<div class='category'>Second</div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='4'>A movie</a></div>

<div class='category'>Third</div>
<div class='service'><a service_id='5'>Blade Runner</a></div>
```

I am note sure how to set up the template correctly to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to pivot your data around, something like this:

```
var categories = {};
$.each(movies, function(i, m) {
    if(!categories[m.Category]) categories[m.Category] = [m];
    else categories[m.Category].push(m);
});
```

Then setup your template to loop though, for example:

```
<script id="mTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(category, movies) $data}}
    <div class='category'>${category}</div>
        {{each(index, movie) movies}}
        <div class='service'><a service_id='${movie.Id}'>${movie.Name}</a></div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then you just call your template passing that pivoted data object as the only argument, like this:

```
$("#mTemplate").tmpl(categories).appendTo("#output");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dw6Dd/).

---

Of course the better option is to do that pivot server-side (and possibly in a different format using an array overall...that would simplify the template), not sure if that's an option or not.